# Filter nested array with objects given a certain ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to get data from a nested array of objects, given an ID that I have.

I have been trying to get data from it so that I can pass it in to Angular Gridster 2, but even when using array.filter, I am struggling to get the results I want.

Data I start with:

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "cols": 15,
      "id": "5-1564645705217",
      "rows": 7,
      "type": 0,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "cols": 15,
      "id": "5-1564645705217",
      "rows": 7,
      "type": 1,
      "x": 15,
      "y": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "cols": 15,
      "id": "5-1564645705217",
      "rows": 8,
      "type": 2,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 7
    },
    "id": "1zk66HvI97C03751LNQm"
  },
  {
    "0": {
      "cols": 5,
      "id": "5-1564545",
      "rows": 7,
      "type": 0,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "cols": 5,
      "id": "5-1564545",
      "rows": 7,
     "type": 1,
      "x": 15,
      "y": 0
    },
    "id": "8gdfg897C03751LNQm"
  }

]
```

I have an id (such as 1zk66HvI97C03751LNQm) and want to be able to fetch the contents so that I end up with:

```
[
  {
    "cols": 15,
    "id": "5-1564645705217",
    "rows": 7,
    "type": 0,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "cols": 15,
    "id": "5-1564645705217",
    "rows": 7,
    "type": 1,
    "x": 15,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "cols": 15,
    "id": "5-1564645705217",
    "rows": 8,
    "type": 2,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.prototype.find` you can easily locate element you want (granted it will only return first found entry, so if your id can be non unique you should use filter instead) after which i remove id from the found object, and turn the rest of the data into desired format.

```js
const data = [{"0": {"cols": 15, "id": "5-1564645705217", "rows": 7, "type": 0, "x": 0, "y": 0}, "1": {"cols": 15, "id": "5-1564645705217", "rows": 7, "type": 1, "x": 15, "y": 0}, "2": {"cols": 15, "id": "5-1564645705217", "rows": 8, "type": 2, "x": 0, "y": 7}, "id": "1zk66HvI97C03751LNQm"}, {"0": {"cols": 5, "id": "5-1564545", "rows": 7, "type": 0, "x": 0, "y": 0}, "1": {"cols": 5, "id": "5-1564545", "rows": 7, "type": 1, "x": 15, "y": 0}, "id": "8gdfg897C03751LNQm"}]
const searchId = "1zk66HvI97C03751LNQm";

const {id, ...elementFound} = data.find(({id})=> id === searchId) || {}; // skip id as unnecessary, return empty object in case of no entries matching search criteria
const elementParsed = Object.values(elementFound); // get values of other fields
console.log(elementParsed);
```